# Method "GetList" does not exist

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, csom

I'm attempting to retrieve the details of a SharePoint list using the following:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext("http://sharepoint/ci"))
{
    var list = ctx.Web.GetList("/ci/resources/Lists/Resource%20Orders/");

    ctx.Load(list);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

When I execute this I'm receiving an unhandled `ServerException` with the details:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

The **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll** I'm using was fetched using Nuget so I believe it's possible that it's not the same version as the one on my clients server (as `web.GetList()` wasn't added until the March 2015 cumulative update).

Am I doing something else wrong or should I be going back to our server team and asking them to bring the servers cumulative updates up to date?

Comment: Try Loading the Web Object before making Call on it : "ctx.Site.Web"

Comment: @MpArvind That doesn't make any sense syntactically? This same code works with SPO also.

Comment: Try using `ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListTitle")` instead.

Comment: @uberz91 That doesn't appear to exist within this namespace or context

Comment: Weird... https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.lists.aspx

Comment: Can you try adding the client.dll from 15 hive and then check for web.lists?

Comment: @Codingo-  I can only think of basic things. 1. Make sure the correct dll versions are loaded  2. Check if the relative Server url is the right one 3. Try to get each object separately and see where the error is thrown

Comment: @MpArvind Agree, I've been working through it and it looks quite likely to be a namespace issue. Will update this question once I have a resolution!

Comment: GetList() method is available only on SP version>=15.0.4701.1001. [Source](http://chuvash.eu/2015/09/15/method-getlist-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @uberz91 for the answer to this one. It appears I was using `getlist()` incorrectly and instead need to use `web.Lists.GetByTitle()` ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.lists.aspx)):

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext("http//sharepoint"))
{
      var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Resource Order Form Content");

      ctx.Load(list);
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: GetList() method is available only on SP version>=15.0.4701.1001. [Source](http://chuvash.eu/2015/09/15/method-getlist-does-not-exist)

Answer (score -1):

```
var clientContext=new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("AdaptorImages");// Get List
var camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();

this.frontPictureItems = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(frontPictureItems, "Include(Id, DisplayName, FileLeafRef,EncodedAbsUrl)");
```

Refer this for more info

https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2015/08/04/content-editor-webpart-slider-using-adaptor-slidercsom/

Comment: This doesn't appear to relate to the question at all...